# Tkinter checkbox (CheckButton) variable changing but indication always false

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Tkinter `CheckButton` attached to a `BooleanVar`and the var is correctly being written to as seen by the print in the command function, however the actual indication on the component always shows that the checkbox is false. When I mouse down on it, the box shows the right state, but as soon as I release the mouse it shows `false` regardless if the variable state is `true` or `false`

This is a cutdown version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
cbvar = BooleanVar()
def getCheckVal():
    print(cbvar.get())
cb = Checkbutton(master, text='From Clipboard', variable=cbvar, command=getCheckVal)
cb.grid(row=0, sticky='new', pady=5)
mainloop()
```

Am I going crazy?

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Did you verify that the cut-down version of the code actually exhibits the problem on your system?

Comment: Most probably the actual code of your application has more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It worked for me. Using Windows10.